# SQL update table 1 with id from table 2 if match the name

Tags: sql, join, sql-update

Can anyone help with the following ?

I have 2 tables and I need to update table#1 with data from table#2 like the example below

Table 1 :

ID - Name - Engine ID

1 - x - NULL

Table 2 :

ID - Name

0 - x

Result (in Table 1) :

ID - Name - Engine ID

1 - x - 0

using loop over table 1

Comment: (1) You cannot use a `select` statement to update data.  (2) You need a database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you haven't tagged your database product, the syntax is almost same for many SQL backends:

```
update table1
set engineId = t2.Id
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.Name = t2.Name;
```

Here is [DBFiddle Demo for SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a6324056abad7132cf0e9c81b408f58)

EDIT: In case you are using MySQL its syntax is slightly peculiar:

```
update Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.Name = t2.Name
set t1.engineId = t2.Id;
```

Comment: but how can i go over the entries and only if the name (or sub name ) in table 1 match or exist in table 2 then update ?

Comment: @samisaw, what do you mean? The code above does that, no?

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, you could do this with a correlated subquery:

```
update t1
set engine_id = (select engine_id from t2 where t2.name = t1.name)
where engine_id is null
```

Note that for this to properly work, there should be no duplicate `name` in `t2` (otherwise, the subquery would possibly return multiple rows, which would cause the query to error).