PostgreSQL: unexpected update all records in database
I have one prod table and one temp.
The task: update all records in prod table with information from temp.
update prod set status = 'on'
  from prod pd
  join temp tm using (factory_id) 
where pd.status = 'off'

unfortunately, that code went to all records in prod table set to 'on', no matter if they are or not in temp.
can you explain how that happened? I thought that only records with status 'off' must be effected.
And what should be corrected in the request to make it right?

This happens because of the from, you should mention prod just once:
update prod set status = 'on'
  from temp tm 
where prod.status = 'off'
and prod.factory_id = tm.factory_id;


much appreciate!
I used the code from example that promised to synchronise two tables: UPDATE Table1
SET value = Table2.value
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.username = Table2.username;

Don't know who gave you this example, but it's a bad one.

here is the link to proposed solution that marked as valid :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064132/sql-update-table-1-with-id-from-table-2-if-match-the-name

@OcMaRUS That's for SQL Server, not for a specific other brand of database. Especially UPDATE can be very different for different databases.
